# Array of yield without comma

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

I'm studying **generator** of javascript ES6.

While I try to understand an example of my book, I got trouble because of an **array of yield without comma** in below code.

How does this code work?

**[ code ]**

```
let gen = function*(){
    return [yield yield]; // how this code line works?
}
let genObj = gen();
console.log(genObj.next());
console.log(genObj.next(10));
console.log(genObj.next(20));
```

**[ run result ]**

```
Object {value: undefined, done: false}
Object {value: 10, done: false}
Object {value: Array[1], done: true}
```

**[ test - 1 ]**

```
let gen = function*(){
    return ['a' 'b'];
}
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

**[ test - 2 ]**

```
let a = [yield yield]

// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm just gonna focus on your first example for this answer:

```
return [yield yield];
```

This line runs from right to left. The right-most `yield` sends a `value` of `undefined` to the caller of the [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) (that's what `genObj` is -- an iterator). On the line where you call `genObj.next(10)`, you're passing `10` into the function `gen()` and resuming its execution at the right-most `yield`, as if the `yield` becomes `10`:

```
return [yield 10];
```

Now the the console logs `10` since that's the next `value` you `yield`. And then you pass in `20` so in effect the function resumes as if:

```
return [20];
```

so the last return `value` that gets logged is an array of `length === 1` containing the value `20`.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is equivalent to the following:

```js
let gen = function*(){
    let x = yield;
    let y = yield x;
    return [y];
}
let genObj = gen();
console.log(genObj.next());
console.log(genObj.next(10));
console.log(genObj.next(20));
```

`[yield yield]` is not an array without a comma between elements, it's an array of a single element, the expression `yield yield`.

`yield yield` evaluates the right `yield` first. It has no argument, so it returns `undefined` from the first call to `.next()`. The second `.next()` passes `10` in, which becomes the result value of `yield`.

This `10` is passed to the second `yield`, showing up as the return value of the second `.next()` call. The third `.next()` call passes `20` in, which becomes the result value of the second `yield`.

The function then wraps this `20` in an array `[` `]` and returns it.